# Using a new windows version of R in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've installed R version 3.5.1 for windows and copied its contents to the R folder used by Anaconda3.   However conda still identifies the current version as 3.4.3.   Is there a "version id" file somewhere in the Anaconda3 folders?

Answer (score 6):

**Short solution**

In short you need to install a the `IRkernel` package in the version of R you  want to use with Jupyter and then make it available to Jupyter. See [here](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/#binary-panel).

**Diagnosis**

You may not be aware that you have two installations of R. To confirm this is the case in a Jupyter Notebook, type:

`R.version`

This should return values such as:

```
               _  
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.3                         
year           2017                        
month          11                          
day            30                          
svn rev        73796                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree
```

Now open RStudio or RGui and input the same command, you should see different output (ignore any warnings):

```
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.0                         
year           2018                        
month          04                          
day            23                          
svn rev        74626                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
nickname       Joy in Playing
```

Note the differences in the `version.string` and `nickname` variables in particular.

Now in your Jupyter notebook type:

`R.home()`

Which will give the output like:

`"C:/Anaconda3/lib/R"`

The same command in RStudio or RGui will return a different path e.g.:

`"C:/R/R-35~1.0"`

The above values may not match those on your machine, but if they are different to each other the following steps will allow you to use the latest R instance from Jupyter.

**Longer solution**

1. Copy the above `R.home()` path from Rstudio (or RGui)
2. Open Anaconda Prompt form the start menu
3. Type `cd /d "C:/R/R-35~1.0"` where the path is the same as the one you have copied. Hit return.
4. Type `cd bin`. Hit return
5. Type `R.exe` to launch the command line R from that directory
6. We now need to install the package `IRkernel`. This package makes the version of R callable as an Jupyter kernel. Type `install.packages('IRkernel')` and hit return.
7. Type `IRkernel::installspec(name = 'ir35', displayname = 'R 3.5.0')` to create the latest R kernel. Note you can change the name and display name to be whatever you wish.
8. Exit R and close any instances of Jupyter Notebooks you have running.
9. Launch Jupyter Notebook again and click to create a new notebook. You should find your kernel available by its display name in the drop down box.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I am very grateful to you.