# how to update R version in jupytor notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, updates

I use the latest version of anaconda to create an environment for R to run

But as I open it with Jupyter notebook and use`R.version` to check the R version,
it shows that my R version is R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05).

However, the latest R version should be 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) or even 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)

So I refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647561/using-a-new-windows-version-of-r-in-jupyter-notebooks) and try to update r version like following：

```
install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec(name = 'ir35', displayname = 'R 3.6.3')
```

then restart the notebook.

But it didn't work. Just nothing happened. No errors are shown.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the command cannot update the .ipynb that was already created under an old version of R.

But the Jupiter environment did provide the new version after the command line `IRkernel::installspec(name = 'ir35', displayname = 'R 4.0.0')`.

It can be used when adding a new Notebook as the following pic. shows：

[image: where you can choose the new R version]

Comment: Thank you S.F. Yeh, however, how does this affect future packages installation?

Answer (score -1):

But previous answer doesn't make any difference cause you just change the name.
check it by writing this prompt "version

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34832825)